Django: Generate multiple random time
I have Schedule class which has dates, routes and time. I have a problem generating random time. I saw this, (Create random time stamp list in python), but it only generate random time which only has minutes gap each.
This is how I did mine, which is just very simple:
no_of_route = int(request.POST.get('no_of_route'))
time = random.sample(range(1, 24), no_of_route)

But this one is just a whole number, I wanted to have results like 9:30, 1:45, and so on. There is no need of min and max time. Is this possible? I'm new to this, so I'm not sure how to do it exactly. Thank you for your help.

Everything is possible. Right no you draw from ints and you are unahappy that you get ints. Well have you tried drawing from what you actually need? (Which we don't even know? is that strings that represent time, is it an actual time like object, something else? [ask] and [mre]

are you looking for generating more than 1 random time based on the number of routes, say for example if no_of_routes is 5, then you need 5 randomly generated times?

I am basing my assumption on the fact that you have a django model in models.py which has 3 fields route,date,time, and thus you want to create number of objects for that model based on no_of_routes.
Regarding generating random time, there are some methods out there that specifically generate times for you, however, I am going to use random.sample() since you seem familiar with it. Firstly, you need to set 2 variables for time, one for hour, and the other for minutes so that the random generated numbers would be like this as an example 9 , 12, now those are 2 randomized numbers, in order to represent those numbers as time, we can use some math to convert those numbers to time object using datetime.time() api:
Here is a model example:
# in models.py

class Schedule(models.Model):
    route = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add =True) # this is used to represent date object (datetime.date)
    time = models.TimeField() # this is used to represent time object (datetime.time)
    

in views.py

# in views.py

def schedule_view(request):
    no_of_routes = int(request.POST('no_of_routes'))

    hours,mins= random.sample(range(1,25), no_of_routes),
    random.sample(range(0,61),no_of_routes)
    
    for i in range(no_of_routes):
        time = datetime.time(hours[i],mins[i],0) #last index represent "seconds"
        schedule_obj = models.Schedule.objects.create(time=time, route = route)

Note 2 things about schedule_view view function:

the range for hours is 25 simply because the end parameter in range() function API is not inclusive.

2.since I don't know the nature of the route (whether it is route name, coordinates, numbers....etc) I left that field for you inside the loop when I am creating Schedule object like this route = route, so be noted about it.
Notice that I haven't added date keyword argument on Schedule object creation inside the loop, simply because the field in Schedule model in models.py has auto_add_now set to True which means, date is automatically added based on the timezone set in settings.py once the object is created inside the loop.
Hope that helped!

This is the outcome I was looking for. You saved my life! This is very detailed, thank you!
